# Creating a function for Road Pricing

Tags: python, function

> The Transport Authority is implementing a new Road Pricing system. The authorities decided that the cars will be charged based on distance travelled, on a per mile basis. A car will be charged $0.50/mi, a van $2.1/mi and taxis travel for free. Create a function to determine how much a particular vehicle would be charged based on a particular distance. The function should take as input the type of the car and the distance travelled, and return the charged price.

The problem above is what I have to do and the code below is what I have so far. The issue I have is that I'm receiving an error for not identifying car, van, and taxi before. But if I do so, it would print out all 3 situations. How would I be able to print out 1 outcome depending on the input for y?

```
    def Road_Pricing():
        x = float(input("How many miles is driven?"))
        y = (input("What car was driven?"))
        if "car":
           print (.50*x)
        if "van": 
           print (2.1*x)
        if "taxi":
           print ("Free")
    Road_Pricing()
```

Comment: Your `if` statements are wrong

Comment: Try `if y == 'car'`. Also, you should be *returning* the value, not printing it

Comment: An important concept for you to understand is python if's check for `truthy` values.  For strings, an empty string is `falsy` and a non-empty string is `truthy`.  Therefore `if "van":` will always cause the van output to print.  That is why you always see output for all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is(emphasis mine):

> ...... The function should take as input the type of the car and the
>   distance travelled, and **return** the charged price.

This means:

1. The function should take two parameters: one for the type of the car and one for the distance travelled.
2. You must return the price(which I suspect is a floating point number), rather than simply printing it.

Another problem in your code is that expressions in your statements isn't checking the value of `car_type`. Also, you should use more meaningful variable names(for example, `distance` and `car_type` instead of `x` and `y`).

```
def road_pricing(car_type, distance):
    if car_type == "car":
       return .50 * distance
    if car_type == "van": 
       return 2.1 * distance
    if car_type == "taxi":
       return 0

car_type = raw_input("What car was driven? ")
distance = float(input("How many miles is driven? "))
print road_pricing(car_type, distance)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I should have realized that I wasn't checking anything with statements.

Comment: Still missing this part: "The function should take as input the type of the car and the distance travelled [...]". Looks like that should be parameters.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, I think you're right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Normality Usually on this site, people don't say "thank you" in the comment under a post. Instead, they [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)(by clicking the large up arrow to the left of a post) and [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/338645) the post that work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare the variable against some strings?

`if y == "car":`

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your `if` statement : firstly you are not checking any condition, secondly `input` returns a `string``

try this out instead :

```
def Road_Pricing():
    x = float(input("How many miles are driven?"))
    type = input("What car was driven?")
    if type == 'car':
       print ("%f$ to pay" %.50*x)
    elif type == 'van': 
       print ("%f$ to pay" %2.1*x)
    elif type == 'taxi':
       print ("Free ride")
pass
```

Comment: You missed this part: "The function should take as input the type of the car and the distance travelled, and return the charged price."